# How to make the top bar menu always visible?

Tags: unity, menu

I just recently started working on Ubuntu, coming from OSX. I work a lot with the computer so I naturally want everything to look and work the way I want it to.

Ubuntu has not let me down yet, but the auto-hiding menu is driving me nuts. How do you deal with it? Is there an easy work-around?

I managed to display the menu for only 10 seconds. I want this menu to be visible at all times

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit if that's any help.